# I removed Pyenv in MAC. How to initialize environment variable?

Tags: pyenv

I have some problems about pyenv in my MAC so I removed it.

After that I open the terminal, always -bash: pyenv: command not found message appear.

I guess this is about environment problem.

How can I solve this?

```
Last login: Wed Jun 19 22:15:19 on ttys000
-bash: pyenv: command not found
-bash: pyenv: command not found
-bash: pyenv: command not found
-bash: pyenv: command not found
-bash: pyenv: command not found
-bash: pyenv: command not found
-bash: pyenv: command not found
ShinTaeyongui-iMac:~ shintaeyong$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A configuration file of your shell (bash) still contains a reference to the `pyenv` command. Depending on how you installed pyenv, this configuration file could be `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` (or both).

The lines you are looking for are probably either (if installed via pipenv-installer):

```
export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

Or (if installed via the manual instructions):

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
```

You should be able to safely remove all lines containing `pipenv`. If you want to be safe, you can disable the lines instead of removing them by adding an `#` in front of them.